# iphone NSInteger issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This seems so basic but for some reason I can't get it to work - the 2 variables are both defined as NSIntegers:

```
if ([AScore == "100"] && [BScore == "100"]) {
       ...
}
```

That doesn't work - nor does it work when I take away the parentheses - nor does it work if I try to implement the 'isEqualToString' command.  I'm sure this is a very basic mistake that i am making.

Comment: The fact Objective-C is one of the few languages which uses square brackets extensively, doesn't mean it uses it for EVERYTHING ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSIntegers aren't objects, nor are strings integers.

Use `if(AScore == 100 && BScore == 100) {` instead.

Comment: Nor are square brackets used for comparisons.