# iphone integer multiplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
[abc = ([def intValue] - 71) * 6];
```

'*' should be the viable way of doing multiplication and 'abc' is defined as an NSInteger.  ('def' is an NSString)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone NSInteger issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055179/iphone-nsinteger-issues)

Comment: This is inadvertently a dupe of the question you asked earlier.

Comment: I suggest you use an `int` rather than an `NSInteger`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use e.g. the following instead:

```
NSInteger abc;
abc = ([def intValue] - 71) * 6;
```

Not everything in Objective-C is of class-type, e.g.:

- `NSInteger`
- `NSUInteger`
- `NSPoint`
- ...

I also don't know where you got that idea of doing the assignment inside the square brackets in the first place - i strongly recommend to read through the [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).